# Int or NSInteger as object for method argument. Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsinteger

I'm having some trouble passing a number as an argument for a method:

```
- (void)meth2:(int)next_int;
```

And to call that method I need this:

```
int next_int = 1;
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) withObject:next_int waitUntilDone:NO];
//update next_int and call meth2 again
```

at this point, I get a "pointer from integer without a cast" error and would happen the same with a `NSInteger`. An `NSNumber` is not useful because it's immutable and I need to change the value constantly.
Any idea how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think [AnthonyF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23837897/1107242) is the only correct answer that works and does not need to change argument types of the method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're just trying to call the method, you could use the standard syntax:

```
[self meth2:next_int];
```

If you really need to use the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` you could wrap the number in an `NSNumber` for the call.  You say you can't do this because you need to change the number, but you can just pull an int out and change that:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:next_int] waitUntilDone:NO];
// ... later ...
- (void)meth2:(NSNumber *)number {
  int myInt = [number intValue];
  // do stuff with myInt
}
```

But maybe you mean that you want to get the value of the number as an output from your call to `meth2`.  If that's what you mean, then you could pass in a double pointer so you can receive a new object back:

```
- (void)meth2:(NSNumber **)number {
  int myInt = [*number intValue];
  // do stuff with myInt
  *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];
}
// The caller can now operate like this:
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:next_int];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) withObject:&number waitUntilDone:YES];
int returnInt = [*number intValue];
```

Of course, that's not really thread-safe, so if you're doing stuff with multiple threads, I would advise using the `@synchronized` keyword for access to multi-thread-accessed variables, or setting up atomic properties (i.e. properties not declared as `nonatomic`).

Also, meth is bad for you!! haha

Comment: Hi Tyler, I'm not sure about the @synchronized keyword, i'll read about, but since this integer variable is used as an 'output' from the thread there's no need to worry about concurrency and stuff.
The ..withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:next_int].. works great, the (NSNumber **) gives me an incompatible pointer type warning.
I'll keep in mind that about meth... thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the integer in an NSNumber before passing it:

```
int next_int = 1
NSNumber *theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:next_int];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) withObject:theNumber waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Then your -meth2: method could look something like this:

```
- (void)meth2:(NSNumber*)theNumber
{
    int next_int = [theNumber intValue];
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of a hack, but this works under ARC:

```
int next_int = 1;
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) 
                       withObject:(__bridge id)(void*)next_int 
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The *__bridge* keyword will tell the compiler to ignore reference counting under ARC, but it requires a pointer, so you first have to cast the int to a C style void pointer.  When your method receives the message it will treat that object pointer as if it's an integer.

Note: If you **can** change the method to take an NSNumber instead of an integer, then that would be the "proper" fix. Unfortunately that's not always possible.

Comment: This is a nice trick if you want to pass an enum, such as when setting an enum property; eg `[cell performSelector:@selector(setSortOrder:) withObject:(__bridge id)(void*)order];`

Comment: I supplement your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62445156/1107242

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `next_int` as the `withObject:` because it's not an Object.

Change your call to:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(meth2:) 
      withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:next_int] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

EDIT:
And change `meth2` to expect an `NSNumber` instead of an `int`.

Comment: That will cause a run-time crash because you also need to modify the method signature to take an `NSNumber`